# Hiding elements via JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Some interesting JavaScript I hadn't seen before:

```
  var html = $( 'html' );
  if( html.className !== '' )
    html.className = '';
```

I’m not sure how it works, but it seems like that assignment has the effect of changing the CSS *display* value of **every element** on the page which has the *className* selector from *block* to *none*.

Is anybody familiar with this behavior? Am I seeing it right?

EDIT:
OK, in response to those who say it's not valid jQuery, you're right. It's a shorthand way of describing the HTML element that was passed in by another function. And I didn't write it, just trying to understand it. It works, I want to know why.

Comment: If it were actually selecitng a DOM element, it would be removing all of the classes on that element... But that is not valid jQuery since there is no className in jQuery. is the code missing a `[0]` ?

Comment: Yes because you are targeting all the HTML.

Comment: @Leon That is just selecting the html element....so unless the html had a rule that had a class that set the display

Comment: This could only work if you define a function named `$` elsewhere, but it certainly isn't valid jQuery. **[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ojrk42c0/)**.

Comment: Have you actually [tested the code](https://jsfiddle.net/zju3un7b/) to see if it actually does what you are suggesting it does? For the code to work one would have to access `className` via `html[ 0 ]` to get the element reference after selecting with jQuery.

Comment: Here's [another example](https://jsfiddle.net/ojrk42c0/2/), which duplicates your code exactly and just adds the missing functionality.

Answer (score -3):

This is actually a jQuery to select the html node and change the value of css class to it.

lets says you want to change the padding of the html document using a click event.

your onclick event would call that function to assign the css class with the desired padding.

Comment: Nope. The jQuery selector is never converted to a standard javascript object for `className` to work.